# Retrieve & Edit a database entry using Entity Framework DBContext Find method

Tags: c#

```
public WarehouseReceipt Receipt { get; set; }
public List<WarehouseReceiptItems> ListReceiptItems { get; set; }

public WarehouseReceiptModel()
{
    Receipt = new WarehouseReceipt();
    ListReceiptItems = new List<WarehouseReceiptItems>();
}
```

I have created a View to capture the WarehouseReceipt fields and a Partial View for each WarehouseReceiptItems. I can Create an entry with no issues. My question is how to Edit an entry using Entity framework Find - this should return all the data back from the database in the appropriate fields.

So far my Find method:

```
public WarehouseReceipt Find(int? id)
{
     //if the ID is not provided
     if (!id.HasValue)
     {
          return new WarehouseReceipt();
     }

     //get the record by id and return
     return new IFAContextModel().WarehouseReceipts.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: Find finds, it doesn't edit. Modify the object you returned and call SaveChanges. BTW your code can easily lead connection leaks and actually *prevents* you from saving the object. Did you check any EF tutorial? They all show how to handle the DbContext, how to modify objects and how to save them

Comment: @Yes how can I find the entry and display the fields including the partial view fields

Comment: Find any of a hundred tutorials then. Retrieving and editing objects is opne the first things all of them show. Don't just post code and expect it to work. Don't post *unrelated* code just to say "here is my code". Try something and if it doesn't work, search SO. If you don't find anything relevant, then ask.